# Why do people prefer jupyter notebook over IDE like VS Code/Spyder?

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook

I see many people in my data science master which use jupyter notebook for programming, even complex and long algorithm are coded in jupyter notebook...

And even outside of my master I see people coding in Jupyter.. Why?
That a real question, I understand jupyter can be nice when you want to do write a report or something, but when you want to build complex app or this kind of thing it doesn't look like a good tool...

Comment: I think people find iteration to be faster/easier. I don't use it.

Comment: _I see people coding in Jupyter.. Why?_ Why don't you ask them?

Comment: You may get a better reception for questions like this at [software recommendations](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/)... although I'm not confident it's on-topic there either. See the [on-topic help](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)

Comment: You might want to read [this meta post](https://softwarerecs.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/196/reverse-recommendations-if-x-is-the-answer-what-is-the-question) before posting this question on software recommendations StackExchange.  It will help you get the best possible response.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The data science and machine learning community seem to overwhelmingly favor Jupyter Notebooks for projects that fall into those domains.
There are two advantages to using Jupyter Notebooks specifically for data science that I would like to highlight:

1. Jupyter Notebooks allows for cell by cell execution of code blocks which some programmers find advantageous because it allows for convenient testing of blocks of code.
2. Jupyter Notebooks allows for Matplotlib inline (%matplotlib inline) which outputs Matplotlib in the Jupyter Notebook which is convenient and allows for somewhat quicker analysis.

Your analysis about Jupyter perhaps not being the best tool for a complex program outside of the data science domain, seems to align with many or even most python developers. Jupyter is another tool that is good to have in your developer toolbox, but probably not the best tool for the development of a complex program outside of the data science realm.

Answer (score 5):

### Divide and conquer

I use Jupyter to build **parts** of a more complex app.

- I first put small pieces of code into a cell, and see the output directly.
- When I'm satisfied, I put this code inside a function, and write a docstring.
- After few tests, I put the code inside a file.py, then I import the function and use it in a new cell to build more complex stuffs.

### Advantages :

- As reactive as an interpreter
- I can see the output directly, even if it's a chart or a pandas dataframe.
- Notebooks are stored on HDD, like an IDE writing a file
- the magics (%timeit, %matplotlib inline...)
- As @Scott pointed out:

  > The magic of this is that I can keep large numpy objects that took a while to make in memory and iterate on various algorithms that I am applying to them. Without jupyter, I would either have to re-create those objects every time, which would be time-consuming, or put in a bunch of code to save them to file and load them from file. It's way easier to just leave them in memory with a jupyter notebook

### Drawbacks:

- Not as complete as an IDE or a text editor (syntax coloration, vim macros, deleting tabs...)
- IPython is not as good as CPython for dealing with heavy multi-threaded app

Comment: This is the same workflow I use with jupyter.  The magic of this is that I can keep large `numpy` objects that took a while to make in memory and iterate on various algorithms that I am applying to them.  Without jupyter, I would either have to re-create those objects every time, which would be time-consuming, or put in a bunch of code to save them to file and load them from file.  It's way easier to just leave them in memory with a jupyter notebook.

Comment: "IPython is not as good as Cython" huh? IPython is a REPL, which not only can you use Cython with, but it even has built in support for it.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga I meant CPython

Comment: IPython isn't another python implementation, it is an augmented REPL which uses CPython.